# Flexbox - как заризинить флекс во флексе?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Доброе утро коллеги. Подскажите. На рисунке два item'а состоящих из иконки и текста. Как мне сделать так , что бы при уменьшении окна браузера эти элементы уменьшались хотя бы на 40%. Я сделал эти item'ы flex'ами и при разрешении 1024px они просто исполняют wrap ) Я не против такого хода событий, но чесслово , хотелось бы перед wrap прыжком, немного их скукожить)  Скорее всего проблема вызвана тем , что размеры той же самой иконки заданы явно, но я не могу обойти это... Возможно стоит зажать оригинальные иконки в padding хмммм ... Подскажите пожалуйста) Спасибо за понимание.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
.service__item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 512px;
    height: 125px;
    border: 2px solid #C4C4C4;
    border-radius: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.item__logo {
    width: 127px;
    height: 102px;
}
.item__text {
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 145%;
    letter-spacing: 4.5%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 349px;
    height: 102px;
    border: 2px solid #6CA09F;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
```

Comment: `{ white-space: nowrap; }`

Comment: Как то только хуже стало, теперь текст просто сплошной строкой выпирает во все стороны вылезая за грани разумного )

Comment: иконки в каком виде?

Comment: svg с фиксированным размером через стили 24х24

Comment: ой, что я несу, написано же  width: 127px;
    height: 102px;   картинки .svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.service__item {
    width: 512px;
    height: 125px;
}
```

Советую убрать вообще. Ширину поставить в процентах (например `width: 50%`), а высоту и вовсе не задавать, чтобы при сжатии экрана не было такого, что текст при переносе будет вылазить за грани блока. Если нужно, можете установить item'ам `min-width`, чтобы они не сильно сжимались и срабатывал `flex-wrap`.

Для более тонкой подгонки используйте медиа-запросы.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!